# Can't create a custom first page footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to create a footer in an article for the first page only, while the rest of the pages are supposed to contain a header and page number at the bottom of the page. Here's the code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage{mathtext}               % русские буквы в фомулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
% Колонтитулы
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{Д.В. Хизанишвили}
\fancyhead[L]{РАЦИО.ru 16(1)}
\fancyhead[C]{}

\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\setlength{\footskip}{40pt} %отступ нижнего колонтитула

\fancypagestyle{firststyle} %новый стиль
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyfootoffset[R]{-12cm} %так можно регулировать ширину колонтитула
   \fancyfoot[L]{РАЦИО.ru 16(1)  \linebreak Д.В. Хизанишвили}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\maketitle
```

The result, however, doesn't meet my expectations: instead of the intended footer the first page contains the page number. Even if I am trying simply to delete page number using `\thispagestyle{empty}` it stays there anyway.

Comment: Swap the order. That is, use `\maketitle \thispagestyle{firststyle}`. It's possible that `\maketitle` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}` (or something similar) which overrides your setting it to `firststyle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\maketitle` is known for setting the page style using

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

and therefore overrides your setting which precedes it. Swap the order to restore peace:

```
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
```

Alternatively, you can adjust the `plain` page style and not have to worry about the first page:

```
\documentclass{article}
%...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set all page styles to 'fancy'
%...
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Overwrite 'plain' page style
  %...
}
%...
\begin{document}

\maketitle% This will override the `fancy` page style with `plain`

%...

\end{document}
```